# Add leading zero to a field without formatting as text

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I have a column of UPC codes, some of which are 7 digits long and I need to convert them to UPCA codes which are 12 digits. I used the VBA below to create a module that I am calling in a query on all of the 7 digit UPCs. The "ItemUPCCode" field is data type short text. If I manually add a zero to a 7 digit code, then it works fine.

Example: I change 7482241 to 07482241 and the result is 074820000041

I want to force the ItemUPCCode column to add a zero in front of all 7 digit UPCs, so that I don't have to manually do it. If I use the Format function, then the result is treated completely like text, so the VBA code doesn't work and spits out "Invalid".

Is there a way to either add the zero without treating it like text or adjust the VBA to compensate?

Here is my module code:

```
Rem ***** BASIC *****
Public Function UPCE2UPCA(ByVal UPCE As String) As String
'
' Convert UPC-E to UPC-A format
'
' Written by Glenn J. Schworak (www.schworak.com)
'
Dim ValidDigits As String
Dim Mfg As String
Dim Prod As String

If Len(UPCE) <> 8 Or (Left(UPCE, 1) <> "0" And Left(UPCE, 1) <> "1") Then
'
' Return INVALID instead of a UPC-A code
'
UPCE2UPCA = "INVALID"
Else
'
' Convert the UPC-E to UPC-A
'
ValidDigits = Mid(UPCE, 2, 6)
Select Case Right(ValidDigits, 1)
Case "0"
Mfg = Left(ValidDigits, 2) & Right(ValidDigits, 1) & "00"
Prod = "00" & Mid(ValidDigits, 3, 3)
Case "1"
Mfg = Left(ValidDigits, 2) & Right(ValidDigits, 1) & "00"
Prod = "00" & Mid(ValidDigits, 3, 3)
Case "2"
Mfg = Left(ValidDigits, 2) & Right(ValidDigits, 1) & "00"
Prod = "00" & Mid(ValidDigits, 3, 3)
Case "3"
Mfg = Left(ValidDigits, 3) & "00"
Prod = "000" & Mid(ValidDigits, 4, 2)
Case "4"
Mfg = Left(ValidDigits, 4) & "0"
Prod = "0000" & Mid(ValidDigits, 6, 1)
Case Else
Mfg = Left(ValidDigits, 5)
Prod = "0000" & Mid(ValidDigits, 6, 1)
End Select
'
' Return the 12 digit UPC-A code
'
UPCE2UPCA = Left(UPCE, 1) & Mfg & Prod & Right(UPCE, 1)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Your numbers *are* text. You're never going to aggregate or add up or calculate the average of UPC codes. Treat them like the text data they are.

Comment: Understood. When I enter the record from the start with a leading zero or manually type a zero to update it, then teh VBA works perfectly. The issue is that if I use the Format function or force the query like "0" + [ItemUPCCode], then it left justifies it and returns "Invalid". The left justification to me implies that it is treating it differently than it originally did.

Comment: Possibly VBA is trying to be smart there; use the `&` *string concatenation* operator to ensure VBA understands both sides of the operator as strings. `+` is ambiguous.

Comment: I actually fixed it rather easily in the VBA. See my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding this to my VBA above:

```
If Len(UPCE) = 7 Then
  UPCE = "0" + UPCE
End If
```

Adding a "0" in front of any 7 digit ItemUPCCode entry. Then it's fixed with the module rather than the query.

Comment: One trick to handle this is to `UPCE=right("00000000" & UPCE,8)`. This prepends 8 zeroes, and then trims the string to 8 characters counted from the right. This works for all cases and eliminates the need to test the length.